# <summary> tag in xml documentation displayed in chm file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-documentation

i document my project by XML Documentation,
"Summary" tag content displayed in Intellisense and tooltips,
i want to know that that content displayed in final chm file too?
or must rewrite that content in other tags such as "remarks" tag?

Comment: Like Jon Skeet pointed out, you need to try first, before asking others. Be brave, and it will make your life brighter in the programming world. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be shown with no problems. What are you using to generate the CHM file? Are you just worried *in case* it doesn't show, or have you had actual problems? Given that I'd expect it to show, I think it would be worth just trying to build the CHM file and checking before you worry any further...

Comment: I use SandCastle, i dont test it, and i only worry about it,

tanx for ur answer

Comment: @HamidrezaShahmoradi: When in doubt, it's always worth trying first. Getting Sandcastle set up the way you want it is far more likely to cause grief than the summary tags :)